# Autofill in vba with value con a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to do a macro to autofill some cells with the value i get from a cell (i have a count if on that cell) this is the current code i have, but i haven't gotten it to work:

```
Sub IDONTKNOWWHATIMDOING()

    Dim Nim As Integer
    Dim Nom As Integer

    Nom = 6

    Nim = Nom + Cells("C2").Value

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(6, 4)).Select
    Selection.AUTOFILL Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 1), _
                        Cells(6, 4)).Select, Type:=xlFillDefault

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Nim, 1), Cells(Nim, 4)).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "i haven't gotten it to work"?  Do you get errors? If so, what is the error and which line raises the error? If not, describe how the resulting output differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

One reason you are getting an error is the `Cell("C2").Value`.  You can't (AFAIK) use `Cell()` like that, instead just use `Range("C2").Value`.  `Cells()` uses `Cells([column],[row])`.  So, if you want to use `Cells()` (which can be helpful later on in looping), `Range("C2")` is the same as `Range(Cells(3,2),Cells(3,2))`.

Also, it's a good idea to reduce/negate the use of `.Select`:

```
Sub IDONTKNOWWHATIMDOING()

    Dim Nim As Integer
    Dim Nom As Integer

    Nom = 6

    Nim = Nom + Range("C2").Value

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(6, 4)).AUTOFILL Range(Cells(6, 1),Cells(6, 4)), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'Why .Select the next range? What do you want to do with it? 
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Nim, 1), Cells(Nim, 4)).Select

End Sub
```

That still gives an error, because your source range and your fill range are the same.  It takes A6:D6 and wants to fill in A6:D6.  If you even change the second cell to `Cells(7,4)`it works.  Just fix the range and you're good to go!

Edit: I assume you don't want to take a range and fill that same range. ...are you trying to take what's in A6, and copy that into B6, C6, and D6?  Or take what's in A6:D6 and paste that into like, F6:I6?
Also, where do you want to use `Nim and Nom` in the main part? They're set to be the same ranges you hard coded with the numbers.